# Espresso InflateException for ImageButton when using `?attr/`

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I have an `ImageButton` like this

```xml
  <ImageButton
            ...
            style="@style/buttonStyle" />
```

where `buttonStyle` looks like this;

```xml
 <style name="buttonStyle">
        ...
        <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
        ...
    </style>
```

When this `ImageButton` is displayed within Espresso tests, it throws

```
android.view.InflateException ... Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
```

When I remove `android:background` attribute, it works fine.

Is there something I'm missing about Android resources on Espresso tests?

Comment: Do you use correct Context with corresponding theme?

Comment: @Bracadabra it was a theme issue as you mentioned. Had to pass theme to the container as following; 
`launchFragmentInContainer<MyFragment>(themeResId = R.style.MyTheme)`

Comment: Great, then I duplicate comment as an answer to not leave  the question without answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to use correct Context with corresponding theme.